# Mismatch between heading and selector when viewing posts on profile page on mobile website

Tags: bug, profile-page, mobile-web

I think I found a minor bug with the mobile version of the website.

If I go to a user's profile page (it has to be a user with a certain number of posts) and scroll down, there is a list of their "Top Posts" with a selector on the right to sort by "Votes" or "Newest", defaulting to "Votes".

If I use the selector to select "Newest" it changes to show "Newest Posts". If I tap one of the posts to read it, and then go back to the profile page using the phone's back button, there is a mismatch where it has reverted to showing "Top Posts" but the selector still says "Newest". To show their newest posts once more, I have to select "Votes" (which does nothing, because it's already showing their top voted posts) and then change it back to "Newest".

Note: It doesn't always default to "Top Posts", it just depends in how you browsed the last profile you viewed. But the weird behavior is the same, just vice versa.

This is on an Android Marshmallow phone in the Chrome browser.

Comment: Pressing the back button is not supported

Comment: Whaddya mean "the back button is not supported", @Tiny? That's the same brokenness that recently afflicted the Developer Survey. Websites should not break the back button. This is a fundamental law of the web.

Comment: @Cody the back button breaks the web all on its own, doesn't need any help from websites to do that. That was more tongue-in-cheek than anything, but I've been told before with similar bugs to not expect sanity when using the back button.

Comment: The back button isn't broken by default—it most definitely *does* need help from the website.

Comment: Any web page that uses JavaScript to modify the DOM is going to be fairly broken. There are steps that can be used to mitigate a lot of this. This is very likely a bug in one of the mitigation techniques used. Again, the first comment was mostly tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @TinyGiant please do not attempt humour when discussing the very serious business of minor UI bugs. Our reason cannot perform its office, whilst we are so benumbed by such ecstasy and rapture.

Comment: I vow to no longer attempt humor when discussing such business. Instead, I will *achieve* humor.